# Creating list inside table list with direction top-to-bottom, left-to-right instead of left-to-right, top-to-bottom

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2013

When I select table cells and click numbering button, numbering list is created in direction left-to-righ, top-to-bottom:

[image]

How do I create lists in table in direction top-to-bottom, left-to-right?
Something like this:

```
1.   |6. 
2.   |7. 
3.   |8.
4.   |9.
5.   |10.
```

Answer (score 1):

*Method 1:* Select just column 1, and apply numbering to it. Select just column 2, and apply numbering to it. Both columns will be numbered from 1. Right-click the number of the first item in column 2, click **Set Numbering Value**, and set a value that's 1 more than the last value in column 1. If you add or remove rows, you'll have to reset the start number in column 2.

*Method 2:* For a table that's, for example, 2 columns wide and 5 rows long, start by inserting a table that's **1** column wide and **10** rows long (so half as wide as you want, twice as long). Select the table, and then, on the **Layout** tab, click **Columns** > **More Columns**. Set the **Number of columns** field to **2**, and set the **Spacing** field to **0**. You'll have what *appears to be* a 2 × 5 table with continuous vertical numbering from one column to the other.

There's possibly a code-based solution, but these are the only methods I know of to do it otherwise.

*Update:* I should note, though it's probably an obvious point, that method 2 only really works when all the items are roughly the same length – specifically, when they are the same number of lines of text. Otherwise, the rows in each column won't line up properly. Still, if the number of lines differ for each item, I suppose you could set a single exact height for all rows in the table (at least as large as required for the longest item) to ensure alignment.